# Searching a Chinese Text Corpus for Sentences That Only Contain Certain Characters

Tags: php, parsing, search, pattern-matching, cjk

Objective: Search through an array of tens of thousands of Chinese sentences in order to locate sentences that exclusively contain characters from a "known characters" array.

For example:
Let's say my corpus consists of the following sentences: 1) 我去中国。 2) 妳爱他。 3) 你在哪里？
I only "know" or want sentences that exclusively contain these characters: 1) 我 2) 中 3) 国 4) 你 5) 在 6) 去 7) 爱 8) 哪 9) 里.
The first sentence would be returned as result because all three of its characters are in my second array. The second sentence would be rejected because I did not ask for 妳 or 他. The third sentence would be returned as a result. The punctuation marks are ignored (as well as any alpha-numeric characters).

I have a working script that does this (below). I'm wondering if this is an efficient way or not. If you are interested, please take a look and suggest changes, write your own, or give some advice. I've gleaned some from [this script](http://www.der-patriotische-kapitalist.de/de/node/14) and checked out some stackoverflow questions, but they didn't address this scenario.

```
<?php
$known_characters = parse_file("FILENAME") // retrieves target characters
$sentences = parse_csv("FILENAME"); // retrieves the text corpus

$number_wanted = 30; // number of sentences to attempt to retrieve

$found = array(); // stores results
$number_found = 0; // number of results
$character_known = false; // assume character is not known
$sentence_known = true; // assume sentence matches target characters

foreach ($sentences as $s) {

    // retrieves an array of the sentence
    $sentence_characters = mb_str_split($s->ttext);

    foreach ($sentence_characters as $sc) {
        // check to see if the character is alpha-numeric or punctuation
        // if so, then ignore.
        $pattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\s\x{3000}-\x{303F}\x{FF00}-\x{FF5A}]/u';
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $sc)) {
            foreach ($known_characters as $kc) {;
                if ($sc==$kc) {
                    // if character is known, move to next character
                    $character_known = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // character is known if it is alpha-numeric or punctuation
            $character_known = true;
        }
        if (!$character_known) {
            // if character is unknown, move to next sentence
            $sentence_known = false;
            break;
        }
        $character_known = false; // reset for next iteration
    }
    if ($sentence_known) {
        // if sentence is known, add it to results array
        $found[] = $s->ttext;
        $number_found = $number_found+1;
    }
    if ($number_found==$number_wanted)
        break; // if required number of results are found, break

    $sentence_known = true; // reset for next iteration 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me this should do it:

```
$pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\x{3000}-\x{303F}\x{FF00}-\x{FF5A}我中国你在去爱哪里]/u';
if (preg_match($pattern, $sentence) {
    // the sentence contains characters besides a-zA-Z0-9, punctuation
    // and the selected characters
} else {
    // the sentence contains only the allowed characters
}
```

Make sure to save your source code file in UTF-8.

Comment: Nice, I appreciate the simplicity. Is there a point at which a regex becomes too long? For instance, if I'm searching for sentences that only contain characters from a set of 2000 different characters, wouldn't that be pushing it?

Comment: Technically that should work fine, probably better than repeatedly looping through 2000 characters. You'd probably not want to store the literal regex for that though, but build it up dynamically.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer, it works great. I'm rather new to regex so I'm very ignorant of what it is capable of.